# ASP.Net - Bootstrap-Badge on button missing after 2nd Postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on my first project utilizing Bootstrap along with ASP.Net. I intend to use Bootstrap badge to indicate counts on LinkButton which I'm using as tabs. The counts are updated on pageload from codebehind.

The count on the badge is being displayed properly upon page load, and it's working on 1st postback too (when switching tab) but on 2nd (and subsequent postback) the button text and the badge icon goes missing for the previous active button.

Below is an example using 2 buttons but my project consists of 4 buttons so the button changes 1 by 1 and not all at a time. In this example I see both buttons going blank at once upon 2nd click.

What am I doing wrong and is there any better way of doing this?

**badge_test.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="badge_test.aspx.cs" Inherits="pages_badge_test" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <meta name = "viewport" content = "width = device-width, initial-scale = 1">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../extras/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
    <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/bootstrap-theme.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkBtnTask" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" role="Button" runat="server" OnClick="lnkbtnMyTasks_Click" >My Tasks<span id="spnMyTask" runat="server" class="badge">0</span></asp:LinkButton>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkBtnReqst" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" role="Button" runat="server" OnClick="lnlbtnMyReqst_Click" >My Requests<span id="spnMyReq" runat="server" class="badge">0</span></asp:LinkButton>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**badge_test.aspx.cs** [Codebehind file]

```
using System;

public partial class pages_badge_test : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        spnMyTask.InnerText = "5";
        spnMyReq.InnerText = "10";
    }
    protected void lnkbtnMyTasks_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lnkBtnTask.CssClass = "btn btn-sm btn-primary";
        lnkBtnReqst.CssClass = "btn btn-sm btn-default";
    }
    protected void lnlbtnMyReqst_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lnkBtnTask.CssClass = "btn btn-sm btn-default";
        lnkBtnReqst.CssClass = "btn btn-sm btn-primary";
    }
}
```

Screenshot on Initial Load (1st button is active), 1st postback (click on 2nd button), 2nd postback (click on 1st button)

[image]

**EDIT:** If I remove the badge and the span tag from linkbutton, it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems ViewState was causing the issue, turned off the view state for the `LinkButton`'s `ViewStateMode="Disabled"` and enabled it for span tag `ViewStateMode="Enabled"` and it started working properly, with badges enabled

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkBtnReqst" ViewStateMode="Disabled" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" 
    role="Button" runat="server" OnClick="lnlbtnMyReqst_Click">My Requests
    <span id="spnMyReq" runat="server" ViewStateMode="Enabled" class="badge">0</span>
</asp:LinkButton>
```